# How to create endpoint with optional array query parameter in akka http?

Tags: scala, akka, openapi, akka-http

My openApi descriptor for optional array query param looks like -

```
- name: groupby
          in: query
          description: groupby
          required: false
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
```

This generates following code -

```
lazy val route: Route =
    path("stats") { (resourceName) => 
      get { 
        parameters("groupby".as[String].?("new ListBuffer[String]() ")) { (groupby) => 
            statusService.getStats(resourceName = resourceName, groupby = groupby)
        }
      }
    }
```

which is not correct. So I tried following to manually create the endpoint -

```
lazy val route: Route =
    path("stats") { (resourceName) => 
      get {
        parameters("groupby".as[String].*) { (groupby) =>
          groupby.size match {
            case 0 => statusService.getStats(resourceName = resourceName, groupby = None)
            case _ => statusService.getStats(resourceName = resourceName, groupby = Some(groupby.toSeq))
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Not sure if this is correct. As, what happens when no parameter is passed in this case?

Can someone share correct way of creating endpoint with optional **array** query parameters in Akka Http?

Comment: take alok to the doc: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#optional-parameter

Comment: I have checked the doc. But my application is using 10.1.12 version of akka http, this optional keyword is not present there.
For this version we use "?" for optional params like -  ```parameters("groupby".?)```

Comment: Your OpenAPI definition is correct. This looks like an issue with the code generator. What generator did you use - Swagger Codegen, OpenAPI Generator, something else?

Comment: So, I am using ```sbt-openapi-generator```  sbt plugin for code generation.